# Clashing class and package when using Android Safe Args

Tags: java, android, android-safe-args

I'm struggling with a really annoying problem with Safe Args in Android (Java).

I have a project structure like this:

```
com.myapp/
├── activites/
│   ├── ActivityA.java
|   |   ├── FragmentA1
|   │   └── FragmentA2
│   └── ActivityB.java
├── view/
|   └── ...
└── model/
    └── ...
```

The important part here is the package **com.myapp.activities.ActivityA**.

When adding some navigation paths to the nav graph, Safe Args generates the structure as following:

```
com.myapp/
└── activites/
    ├── ActivityA/
    |   ├── FragmentA1Directions
    │   └── FragmentA2Directions
    └── ...
```

In this case I cannot compile my project because I get the error

> error: class ActivityA clashes with package of same name.

This makes totally sense to me as the class *com.myapp.activities.ActivityA* gets generated to package *com.myapp.activities.ActivityA* but somehow I don't understand how I should avoid this problem.
Is there something completely wrong my folder structure?

Comment: So just to clarify, your `FragmentA1` and `FragmentA2` are static inner classes of `ActivityA`? Do you see the same issue when you have them as separate classes?

Comment: Exactly. To be more precise, ActivityA is a Setting Activity and `FragmentA1` and `FragmentA2` are static `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. I did not try to move them out yet - I couldn't imagine that I am the only one facing this situation (combining Safe Args with split Preference fragments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of Fragments in an Activity seems really not to work.

I put the Fragments into separate files to make it work like suggested by @ianhanniballake.